# how can I swap two strings in a string-array of pointers in C without using other arrays?

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, swap

```
int main(){

char* ants[5]={"red ant" ,"blue ant" ,"green ant" ,"yellow ant" ,"white ant"};

.... }
```

how can I swap two strings if I want to swap `"red ant"` and `"white ant"` ?
can someone help me write the code (without using another array at all)???

Comment: The same way you swap any other two values. Use a temporary variable to hold one of the values, assign that value with the other value, then assign the other with the temporary.

Comment: `temp = x; x = y; y = temp;`

Comment: if i hold the value which is in this case a string then I have to have a temp string  and string is an array of characters then I cant do that (i have  noted  in the question I cant use another array other than char* ants)

Comment: @nena your value is a pointer to a string, not the string itself.

Comment: doesn't it matter that the length of the two strings isn't the same?

Comment: Tip: Instead of fixed-length arrays where you might miscalculate something use `NULL` terminated ones, as in `char* ants[] = { "red", ..., NULL }`.

Comment: @IvanC can u show me how to do that?

Comment: @tadman  this array is given as a homework  so I can change nothing

Comment: Fair enough. Just saying that in general if you do it that way it's *way* easier to deal with.

Comment: @costaparas can u show me how to do that in a code ?

Comment: String literals are read-only, so you can't swap the contents. All you can do is swap the pointers.

Comment: can u explain to me why are they only for read? @Barmar

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string-initialized-with-cha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The strings used for the types of ants are *String-Literals* and on all but non-conforming compilers are read-only (non-mutable). A string literal has the type *array of characters* with the length set to contain the characters and the `'\0'` (nul-terminating characer). The standard section for string literals is [C11 Standard - 6.4.5 String literals](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5)

You cannot change the contents of the string literals, but you can change which pointer points to which string-literal. In your case you have:

```
    char *ants[5]={"red ant" ,"blue ant" ,"green ant" ,"yellow ant" ,"white ant"};
```

Which has the type *Array of Pointers to* `char`. So you have an array of character pointers. Each of the pointers in the array holds the address of one of the strings in `ants`. To change the order of the strings in `ants` you have to `swap` the addresses held by the pointers in your array.

A trivial example to swap the red and blue ants could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    char *ants[5]={"red ant" ,"blue ant" ,"green ant" ,"yellow ant" ,"white ant"};
    int n = sizeof ants / sizeof *ants;         /* number of ants */
    
    char *t = ants[0];                          /* temp pointer holding 1st address */
    ants[0] = ants[1];                          /* assign 2nd address to 1st pointer */
    ants[1] = t;                                /* assign temp pointer to 2nd */
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)                 /* output swapped ants */
        puts (ants[i]);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/swap_ants
blue ant
red ant
green ant
yellow ant
white ant
```

If you wanted to write a `swap()` function to swap the pointers, you cannot just pass the pointers as arguments, e.g., you could NOT write:

```
swap (char *a, char *b)
```

and then swap `a` and `b` in the function. Why? The pointers `a` and `b` are **copies** of the actual pointers. They are local variables for the `swap()` function. Therefore, nothing you do to them in the function would be seen back in `main()`.

You CAN provide the address of the pointers as the arguments and then swap the pointers at those two addresses and the changes WILL be seen back in `main()`. By passing the actual address of the original pointer, any changes made are made to the values at the original address and are available back in `main()`. So a `swap()` function for two pointers could be written as:

```
/** swap pointers, changing pointer at address */
void swapptr (char **a, char **b)
{
    char *t = *a;           /* pointer at a's address saved in t */
         *a = *b;           /* assign pointer from b to a */
         *b = t;            /* assign temp pointer t to b */
}
```

Now if you wanted to swap the red and blue ants, you could simply call the `swapptr()` function passing the address of each of the pointers, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/** swap pointers, changing pointer at address */
void swapptr (char **a, char **b)
{
    char *t = *a;           /* pointer at a's address saved in t */
         *a = *b;           /* assign pointer from b to a */
         *b = t;            /* assign temp pointer t to b */
}

int main(){

    char *ants[5]={"red ant" ,"blue ant" ,"green ant" ,"yellow ant" ,"white ant"};
    int n = sizeof ants / sizeof *ants;         /* number of ants */
    
    swapptr (ants, ants + 1);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)                 /* output swapped ants */
        puts (ants[i]);
}
```

(same output)

**Note:** you have to pay attention to the types. `ants` (which is `ants+0`), and `ants + 1` are pointers to your string literals, they are pointers to an array of chars. But on access, an array of Type in C is converted to a pointer to the first element. [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) So each and is a *pointer to* a *pointer to* the first character in each. So each element has the type `char**` to begin with. So that's why you can pass `ants + 0, ants + 1` to swap the first and second (red and blue) ants.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: many many thanks!! for your time and effort ,it helped so much .

Comment: You are very welcome. Good luck with your coding!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know a char* is a POINTER to an adress record.
So if you define `char *temp;` and use this variable to store the pointer to ants[0] you technically didn't create a different array to create the new order.

```
char *temp;

temp=ants[0];
ants[0]=ants[4];
ants[4]=temp;
```

And the places are exchanged...