# Manipulation of Strings inside a function

Tags: arrays, c, string

I've been stuck at this for a while.

Let there be an array of strings declared by user:

```
#define LENGTH 3

int main()
{
  char* hohoho[3]={"string1","string2","string3"};
  foo1(hohoho);
  for(i=0; i<LENGTH-1; i++)
    {
        printf("%s, ",hohoho[i]);
    }
  printf("%s.",hohoho[LENGTH-1]);
  return 0;
}

  foo1(char** array);
{
/*moving array 1 time left and placing first one at the end*/
}
```

expected: `string2, string3, string1.`

I have tried changing strings with a tmp `*char`,
I have tried changing them by address,
cant find info on the web on how to approach this exercise.
to my understanding I cant change the strings themselves because they are considered to be only read strings.
I cannot use malloc or any helping array for that matter.

Comment: `"string1","string2","string3"` are *String-Literals* that reside in read-only memory on standards conforming systems. `hohoho` is an array of pointers to string-literals. You need `char hohoho[3][10] = {...}` if you intend to manipulate the content of the strings.  `foo` will then be `foo1(char (*)[10] array);` See also: [C11 Standard - §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup(p1)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1). See also: [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

Comment: For `LENGTH` you mean `3` isn't it?

Comment: As written you CAN swap pointers in `foo()`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin 
yes LENGTH is 3 sorry forgot to mention that,
i cant change the initial array declaration so it must be a char* []
also, i cant use brackets, its a pointer only exercise.

Comment: also the link you posted is broken :(

Comment: Then in `foo1()` you want `char *tmp = array[0]; array[0] = array[2]; array[2] = tmp;`

Comment: See [C11 Standard - 5.1.2 Execution environments](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2) and next 2 sections.

Comment: Based on your current code, it seems what you want is covered here more or less: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65376006/how-can-i-swap-two-strings-in-a-string-array-of-pointers-in-c-without-using-othe/65376520#65376520

Comment: @costaparas that's exactly what i need just a bit simpler, amazing thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`array` is a pointer to the array containing pointers to the strings, so you can change the pointers in the array from the function.

From this point it's just a matter of how to shuffle the pointers the way you want. This is basically a longer version of swapping two variables, as in:

```
tmp_s = s1;
s1 = s2;
s2 = tmp_s;
```

If these were in an array, it would look like:

```
tmp_s = s[0];
s[0] = s[1];
s[1] = tmp_s;
```

Since you have an array of multiple values, you'll need a loop for the middle part (`s[i] = s[i+1]`). The complication here is that you need to know the length of the array. Normally that would be another value passed in to your `foo1()` function, or the array would have a placeholder value indicating the end of values (e.g. `a = {"a", "b", "c", NULL}`).

If you're not allowed to change the array declaration or function parameters, you'll just have to assume the array length a constant - looks like LENGTH is defined to be 3 so you can use that.

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't understand your `"moving array 1 time left"` comment, I presume it means rotate all elements to the left by 1 so you end up with `"string2", "string3", "string1"`, and then swapping first/last would end up with `"string1", "string3", "string2"` (effectively swapping the 2nd and 3rd elements as the final result)

As mentioned, you have an *array-of-pointers-to string-literals*, so the content of the strings is immutable, but you can swap the order of the pointers. If you take the logic above, and apply the left-rotate and swap first/last your `foo1()` function could be:

```
void foo1 (char **array)
{
    /*moving array 1 time left and placing first one at the end*/
    char *tmp = array[0];
    
    for (int i = 1; i < LENGTH; i++)    /* move all elements left by 1 */
        array[i-1] = array[i];
    array[LENGTH-1] = tmp;
    
    tmp = array[0];                     /* swap 1st and last */
    array[0] = array[LENGTH-1];
    array[LENGTH-1] = tmp;
}
```

(**note:** if you don't need the left-rotate of elements, you can delete that part of the code)

If you add the header required, the full code could be written as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LENGTH 3

void foo1 (char **array)
{
    /*moving array 1 time left and placing first one at the end*/
    char *tmp = array[0];
    
    for (int i = 1; i < LENGTH; i++)    /* move all elements left by 1 */
        array[i-1] = array[i];
    array[LENGTH-1] = tmp;
    
    tmp = array[0];                     /* swap 1st and last */
    array[0] = array[LENGTH-1];
    array[LENGTH-1] = tmp;
}

int main (void) {

    char *hohoho[] = {"string1", "string2", "string3"};
    
    puts ("original order:");
    for (int i=0; i<LENGTH; i++)
        puts (hohoho[i]);
    
    foo1 (hohoho);
    
    puts("\norder after rotating left 1 and swapping first/last:");
    for (int i=0; i<LENGTH; i++)
        puts (hohoho[i]);
    
    printf ("\n%s.\n", hohoho[LENGTH-1]);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/swap_arr_of_ptrs
original order:
string1
string2
string3

order after rotating left 1 and swapping first/last:
string1
string3
string2

string2.
```

(no idea why you include the last output, but it was there...)

Look things over and let me know if I have the logic of the `"moving array 1 time left"` part wrong or if you have further questions.